# Will AWS Backup Service restart my EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup

I am currently configuring my production instances to use AWS Backup Service rather than Lamdba. However, I notice AWS Backup Service does not have the "no reboot" option or anything mentioning that it will not reboot the EC2 instances.

Hence, Will AWS Backup Service restart my EC2 instances during the backup(create AMI) process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not reboot your instance. I checked that using on-demand backup of my instance. Then in CloudTrial I verified that the `CreateImage` API call made by the backup is set with `"noReboot": true`:

From CloudTrial event (part shown):

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "xxxx:AWSBackup-AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole/AWSBackup-AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole",

    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateImage",

    "requestParameters": {
        "description": "This image is created by the AWS Backup service.",
        "noReboot": true
    },  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. Now I also learnt that I could check the requestParameters via CloudTrail.

Comment: @TsuWeiQuan No problem. CloudTrial can be useful in many cases:-)